# Change path to layer?

Tags: arcpy, layer-file

I have script that should add lyr file from server.
It is like a multiple symbology to certain layerin TOC, i.e. I have a feature class called *tline* and different symbology layers like *tlineA, tlineB*.
My goal is to have independent tline layer and upload tlineA and tlineB layers to TOC and change their data sources. 
I made a script tool that already can read paths to *tline* and *tlineA, tlineB* and should change the data source of *tlineA*

Here is it

```
ab = arcpy.Describe("tline")
path = ab.path
ao = arcpy.Describe("tlineA")
peth=ao.path

for lyr in arcpy.mapping.ListLayers(mxd, "",df):
     if lyr.name == "tlineA":
         lyr.findAndReplaceWorkspacePath (peth,path)
         print lyr.dataSource
```

But anyway the datasource of tlineA remains the same as it was before.
I also tried like

```
lyr.findAndReplaceWorkspacePath (r"ao",r"ab")
```

But still doesn't work.

Comment: @GISGe corrected

Comment: Can you show more of your script? Does `mxd` reference the currently open mxd, or an mxd on your disk?

Comment: If this is a Python script tool, does it have any parameters?  What do you mean when you say "doesn't work"?

Comment: @GISGe added full script

Comment: @PolyGeo it doesn't have parameters I want just to import symbology layers to TOC with a reference to initial tline layer which can be taken from any gdb file.

Comment: Are you saying that you just Add Script this into a standard toolbox and then run it with a Layer of that name in the currently open MXD?  What happens when you do that?

Comment: The full script firstly adds symbology layers to TOC, then it changes tline's appearance to lyr file in TOC. Finally, it removes symbology layer from TOC leaving only tline with new symbology

Comment: Recently I've figured out how to change a path. I used `lyr.replaceDataSource `. It completely changes path to data sourse of lyr file  and apply the attribute information of main tline layer. However, the when I turn it visible, it is blank. And for some reason I cannot use variable as path for change, the only way right now is to write the whole path to GDB like `lyr.replaceDataSource (r"D:\Folder\London.gdb","FILEGDB_WORKSPACE","",True)`

Comment: Please [edit] your question so that we know what you are *currently* trying and are *currently* stuck.